# Python: Accessing a new <tr> while inside a different <tr> with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am trying to gather some data by webscraping a local HTML file using BeautifulSoup4. The problem is, that the information I'm trying to get is on different rows that have the same class tags. I'm not sure about how to access them. The following html screenshot contains the two rows I'm accessing with the data I need highlighted (sensitive info is scribbled out). [image]

The code I have currently is:

```
def find_data(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as html_file:
         soup = bs(html_file, "lxml")
    hline1 = soup.find("td", class_="headerTableEntry")
    hline2 = hline1.find_next_sibling("td")
    hline3 = hline2.find_next_sibling("td")
    hline4 = hline3.find_next_sibling("td", class_="headerTableEntry")

    line1 = hline1.text
    line2 = hline2.text
    line3 = hline3.text
    #Nothing yet for lines 4,5,6
```

The first 3 lines work great and give 13, 39, and 33.3% as they should. But for line 4 (which should be the second  tag and first  tag with class=headerTableEntry) I get an error "'NoneType' object is not callable".

My question is, is there a different way to go at this so I can access all 6 data cells or is there a way to edit how I wrote line 4 to work? Thank you for your help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question with actual html, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<tr>` tag is not inside another `<tr>` tag as you can see that first `<tr>` tag is closed with the `</tr>` So that next `<td>` is not a sibling of the previous, hence it returns None. It's within the next `<tr>` tag.

Pandas is a great package to parse html `<table>` tags (which this is). It actually uses beautifulsoup under the hood. Just get the full table, and slice the table for the columns you want:

```
html_file = '''<table>
<tr>
<td class="headerName">File:</td>
<td class="HeaderValue">Some Value</td>
<td></td>
<td class="headerName">Lines:</td>
<td class="headerTableEntry">13</td>
<td class="headerTableEntry">39</td>
<td class="headerTableEntry" style="back-ground-color:LightPink">33.3 %</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerName">Date:</td>
<td class="HeaderValue">2020-06-18 11:15:19</td>
<td></td>
<td class="headerName">Branches:</td>
<td class="headerTableEntry">10</td>
<td class="headerTableEntry">12</td>
<td class="headerTableEntry" style="back-ground-color:#FFFF55">83.3 %</td>
</tr>
</table>'''



import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(html_file)[0]
df = df.iloc[:,3:]
```

**So for your code:**

```
def find_data(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as html_file:
        df = pd.read_html(html_file)[0].iloc[:,3:]
        print (df)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
           3   4   5       6
0     Lines:  13  39  33.3 %
1  Branches:  10  12  83.3 %
```